# How to get File Name of External File for an Existing Connections - Excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I import an External text file (.csv) to my excel worksheet named "SourceData".

The connection is called "Data". Every time I refresh my workbook, excel will ask me to choose my source file. My source files same data structure, and they are automatically generated by other database:

```
           REPL_STATS_010314130000.CSV

           REPL_STATS_030314060001.CSV
           ....
```

My question is:

- **How can I get the file name of my external csv file that currently imported to my worksheet "SourceData" so when I refresh the connection, This name is displayed in a cell (for example A1) in another sheet named "Summary"**

For example: after I click refresh all, choosing file "REPL_STATS_010314130000.CSV" to update my data source, then cell A1 will display "REPL_STATS_010314130000.CSV"

I try to search for a solution a few days already, but I can't get it work.

Can you suggest form VBA code that can get this information?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can split (eg) `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SourceData").QueryTables("Data").Connection` on `\\` and take the last element of the resulting array - that will be the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim Williams suggestion I write the following code, and put this code in Sheet1(SourceData):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim ConSource As String

   ConSource = Worksheets("SourceData").QueryTables("Data").Connection

   Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value = "Source:   " & Right(ConSource, Len(ConSource) - InStrRev(ConSource, "\"))

   ConSource = ""

End Sub
```